# Glide 4.X: DataFetcher - attempt to load a picture from ZIP file

Tags: android, zip, android-glide, zipinputstream, appglidemodule

I have to decrypt image and load it to ImageView by means of `Glide` with a constraint to **do not save decrypted images on the disk**. As I know `Glide` has an opportunity to do that with `DataFetcher`. As an example of a `DataFetcher` usage I would like do load an image from a `zip` file first.

A have read [Writing a custom ModelLoader](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/tut/custom-modelloader.html#writing-a-custom-modelloader) and on the base of [author's repository](https://github.com/sjudd/Base64ModelLoaderExample) I have created [my own repository](https://github.com/isabsent/Base64ModelLoaderExample) with an attempt to rewrite the code for the case of unzipping a single picture `zip` file inside of `DataFetcher.loadData` method and load it to `ImageView`.

```
public class FileDataFetcher implements DataFetcher<InputStream> {
    private final FileEnveloper fileEnveloper;

    FileDataFetcher(FileEnveloper fileEnveloper) {
        this.fileEnveloper = fileEnveloper;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadData(@NonNull Priority priority, DataCallback<? super InputStream> callback) {
        try {
            unzip(); //Works fine!

            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileEnveloper.getFile());
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            callback.onDataReady(zin);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            callback.onLoadFailed(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        // Intentionally empty only because we're not opening an InputStream or another I/O resource!
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        // Intentionally empty.
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Class<InputStream> getDataClass() {
        return InputStream.class;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSource.LOCAL;
    }

    private void unzip() throws IOException {
        String location = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator ;
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileEnveloper.getFile());
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                File dir = new File(location + ze.getName());
                if (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory())
                    dir.mkdirs();
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                zin.closeEntry();
                fout.close();
            }
        }
        zin.close();
    }
}
```

Method `unzip()` works fine and desired unzipped picture appears on the disk, but `callback.onDataReady(zin)` leads to the stack trace:

```
2019-12-22 13:57:22.605 28803-28803/judds.github.com.base64modelloaderexample W/Glide: Load failed for judds.github.com.base64modelloaderexample.FileEnveloper@2d3a6e1c with size [720x1257]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
  Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ZipInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
    Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ZipInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
    Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ZipInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
    Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ZipInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
```

I suppose the reason is not in `Glide` but in the wrong usage of `ZipInputStream` with `Glide`.  Does anybody know how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

To get it work (for single file in `zip`-archive) we have to set `ZipInputStream` in the initial position with `zin.getNextEntry()` as follows:

```
@Override
public void loadData(@NonNull Priority priority, DataCallback<? super InputStream> callback) {
    try {
        unzip(); //Works fine!

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileEnveloper.getFile());
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        zin.getNextEntry();//Essential!!!
        callback.onDataReady(zin);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        callback.onLoadFailed(e);
    }
}
```